# Creating an Instance of Class in IOS 6

Tags: objective-c, class, ios6, instance

I have a problem that I hope you can help me with. I have an app with several storyboard views, each with a separate viewcontroller. I want to be able to use my own class in all views in the storyboard. This will make the code in each viewcontroller much cleaner and the whole app easier to debug etc. The class will contain variables and methods.

The overall aim for me is to collect data from the user via buttons and then store these in a database. It will be possible to view and amend data, as well as generating statistics.

As most variables and methods will be used in different views and at different times, I would like to separate all these in separate files.

I can also tell you that this is not a lazy short-cut attempt from me, I have surfed the internet for many, many hours reading hundreds of posts etc and I am still nowhere nearer a solution.

Any input is very much appreciated!

Thank you for taking your time to read this...

SomeClass.h has the following code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SomeClass : NSObject
{
NSString *dataOne;
NSString *dataTwo;
NSString *dataThree;
}

- (void) SetDataOne: (NSString*) dataOneReceived;
- (void) SetDataTwo: (NSString*) dataTwoReceived;
- (void) SetDataThree: (NSString*) dataThreeReceived;
- (void) saveSomeData;

@end
```

---

SomeClass.m has the following code:

```
#import "SomeClass.h"

@implementation SomeClass   

- (void) SetDataOne: (NSString*) dataOneReceived {
    dataOne = dataOneReceived;
}

- (void) SetDataTwo: (NSString*) dataTwoReceived {
    dataTwo = dataTwoReceived;
}

- (void) SetDataThree: (NSString*) dataThreeReceived {
    dataThree = dataThreeReceived;
}


- (void) saveSomeData {
    // Here I do stuff with dataOne etc…
}



@end
```

---

SomeView.h has the following code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "HeadViewController.h"
#import "SomeClass.h"


@interface SomeView : UIViewController

// contains stuff not needed to show here

- (IBAction)Done:(id)sender;

@end
```

---

SomeView.m has the following code:

```
#import "SomeView.h"
#import "SomeClass.h"


@interface SomeView ()

@end

@implementation SomeView


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    SomeClass *someClassObject = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

// Other standard methods omitted


- (IBAction)Done:(id)sender {

    [someClassObject SetDataOne: @”whatever text”];
    [someClassObject SetDataTwo: @”whatever text”];
    [someClassObject SetDataThree: @”whatever text”];
    [someClassObject SaveSomeData];

    Error Msg for all the above: ”Use of Undeclared Identifier ’someClassObject’
}

@end
```

---

Comment: You can see the error message I get at the end of the code above. I have no clue what I am doing wrong. I have looked at a lot of examples on how to create and call classes, but cannot seem anything that solves my problem. Also, I see that some of the put the ”SomeClass *someClassObject = [[SomeClass alloc] init];” in the ”main.m file”. If I understand correctly, that file is the first one to load when app starts. If so, then I cannot place it there as I will have to create instances of my class in several different views and other times than when the app starts. That is why I have placed it in the viewDidLoad-method.

Comment: "that file is the first one to load when app starts" - I'd suggest you go back one step and learn C well before trying to dive deep into iOS development. Files aren't loaded, instead functions are called, `main()` is the first to that.

Comment: Narrow down your question and remove the unnecessary code snippets. In its current form this is a question leading nowhere.

Comment: I think you need to find a few good books on programming.  "Surfing the internet for hours" is not the way to learn programming.

Comment: Hot Licks - you have a suggestion for a good book which is for beginners yet very detailed?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of thoughts:

1. You've made `someClassObject` a local variable of the `viewDidLoad` method. Looks like you meant to make it a class instance variable (or, better, a private class property, which will have the instance variable synthesized for you). Thus:

   ```
   @interface SomeView ()

   @property (nonatomic, strong) SomeClass *someClassObject;

   @end

   @implementation SomeView

   - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       self.someClassObject = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
   }

   - (IBAction)done:(id)sender {

       [self.someClassObject setDataOne: @"whatever text"];
       [self.someClassObject setDataTwo: @"whatever text"];
       [self.someClassObject setDataThree: @"whatever text"];
       [self.someClassObject saveSomeData];

       // should resolve the Error Msg for all the above: ”Use of Undeclared Identifier ’someClassObject’
   }
   ```
2. BTW, as a matter of convention, your [method names should start with a lowercase letter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-BCIGIJJF) (e.g. `setDataOne` not `SetDataOne`, `done` rather than `Done`, etc.), as illustrated above.
3. If you're going to write your own setters, `setDataOne`, `setDataTwo`, etc., you might as well remove those three instance variables, remove your three `setData___` methods, and  replace the three instance variables with class properties (and let the compiler synthesize not only the instance variables, but the setters, too).

Comment: Thanks for taking your time, much appreciated!
As far as 1. goes, it seems to be fine in my program, other than the fact that it complains about the "@" sign before the "whatever text".
As far as 2. goes, point noted.

Comment: And finally as far as three is concerned, I will try this, it seems much more neat and simple, thanks!

Comment: @MrEmkei Regarding the complaining about the "@", I suspect it is really complaining about the quotation marks. I just cut and pasted your code, but I notice that you original code sample was using curly quotation marks ("closing" quotation marks) and I have updated my answer to use plain old quotation marks. Perhaps you edited the question in some Word processor that replaced the standard quotation mark with the curly rendition. (I know they look similar, but they're entirely different characters.)

Comment: I have made changes in your third example, so that in the SomeClass.h I declare the following NSString properties:dataOne, dataTwo, dataThree.

Then I do the following in the SomeView.m:
SomeClass *someClassObject = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
someClassObject.dataOne = @”whatever text”];
someClassObject.dataTwo = @”whatever text”];
someClassObject.dataThree = @”whatever text”];
[someClassObject saveSomeData];

Stil get an error msg: "No visible @interface for..." for the last row.

Comment: Rob, thanks for the thoughts on the "@" sign, will check that out.

Comment: I should clarify that I get the "No visible @interface for..." for the following entry: [someClassObject saveSomeData].
Is there any comprehensive book on or which contains a lot of information about classes?

Comment: @MrEmkei First, you have a bunch of extra `]` in there. It should be `SomeClass *someClassObject = [[SomeClass alloc] init]; someClassObject.dataOne = @"whatever text"; someClassObject.dataTwo = @"whatever text"; someClassObject.dataThree = @"whatever text"; [someClassObject saveSomeData];`

Comment: @MrEmkei I personally think that watching some good training videos would be well advised, such as Stanford University's various courses in iTunes U. Re good books, see if those courses use a particular book, and if so, get that. If not I don't have specific recommendations but I'm sure if you google "best iOS development book", you'll get lots of promising leads.

Comment: Not sure where those extra "]" came from, they are not in my code. Anyways, the last piece of error was due to a typo which I found today. Thanks for taking your time and helping me with this, now I can finally start building the app in more detail using classes :-) I will check up Stanford, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

someClassObject is set inside viewDidLoad and because it is not stored anywhere inside the view will be deleted at the end of that very same method

Answer (score 0):

You should add your object inside each header file's interface section like this:

SomeView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "HeadViewController.h"
#import "SomeClass.h"


@interface SomeView : UIViewController
{
 SomeClass *someClassObject;
}

// contains stuff not needed to show here

- (IBAction)Done:(id)sender;

@end
```

Then when you instantiate `someClassObject` inside ViewDidLoad it will persist throughout that view.

Comment: Thanks!
But it does not work, I get the err msg "No visible @interface for 'TeeStat'declares the selector 'SetClubHit' etc...